# make:***no rule to create object"@GDB_OBJ@"`

Tags: linux, gcc, vim

I want to install `vimgdb`,in the directory `~/vim/vim73/src`. Execute `./configure` and make.

The error message was:`make:***no rule to create object"@GDB_OBJ@"`.

I tried to use:`make "CFLAGS="-O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1"`,the result was the same as before.So what should I do to compile it successfully?

Comment: If you are referring to [this vimgdb](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3039), why don't you follow the installation procedure? What do you want to compile? Why?

Comment: I already follow the installation, but still report the same error.

Comment: The installation process of that vimgdb plugin (if that's the right one) doesn't involve compiling anything so why and what are you compiling?

Answer (score 0):

The installation instructions I found say:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: you must run make (not ./configure), and if you run ./configure then you must add the --enable-gdb command line argument in order to include the gdb feature (vimgdb) in vim.